# How do I parse through the results of .get so that I only have the links in the anchor tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get just an array returned with all the links at the given link?

```
$.get( "http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/biological-engineering/20-010j-introduction-to-bioengineering-be-010j-spring-2006/lecture-notes/", function( data ) {
  alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
});
```

Comment: You cannot make Ajax calls to external URLs, unless the server explicitly allows it. Use a server side language instead if you want to scrape arbitrary websites.

Comment: [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)

Comment: If you just want an array of the links type `$x("//a")` in your chrome console window (ctrl - shft - i, then click on console).

Answer (score 0):

you could use regular expressions. say start with this

```
data.match(/<a.+?href=('|")([^\1]+?)\1/mg).map(function(m) { console.log(m) });
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct, you cannot make **direct** ajax calls to external URLs. However, **can** do that with YQL and jQuery, like so:

HTML -

```
<ul id="list">
</ul>
```

JS -

```
var url = encodeURIComponent("select * from html where url='http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/biological-engineering/20-010j-introduction-to-bioengineering-be-010j-spring-2006/lecture-notes' and xpath='//a/@href'");

var yql = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=" + url + "&format=json";

$.getJSON(yql,
          function(data) {
              $.each(data.query.results.a, function(i, item) {
                  $('#list').append('<li>'+item.href+'</li>');
              });       
          }
);
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/55QV9/